# socket.io undefined and refusing connection

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, socket.io

[image][image]I am using socket.io to display a message but when I run node server.js it does not console log any of the output message. I have attached my chat.html, server.js and main.js file to show the socket.io code.

chat.html

```
<script src="http://localhost:54159/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

server.js

```
const http = require('http'); 
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io'); 

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app); 
const io = socketio(server); 

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    
    console.log('New web socket connection...'); 
    socket.emit('message', 'Welcome to Chat Room!');
    
}); 


const PORT = 54159 || process.env.PORT; 

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

main.js
`const socket = io();`

Comment: Did you check the browser dev console to see if there are script errors or loading errors in your web page?  It seems likely that one of your scripts is not properly loading in the web page and thus no socket.io connection.

Comment: I am confused how to do that. I defined the port to be 58228 in google chrome but in Brackets where I am doing the code it says the local host is 8123. Also when I load it, it sometimes switches ports so I am kind of confused as to how to fix that.

Comment: I added a picture of the errors I am getting. I am so confused, please help!

Comment: Well, the client HAS to know what port you're running on.  No way to make a connection to your server if it doesn't know the port.

Comment: It appears that `54159` is NOT the correct port for your server and that's what you're using here: `<script src="http://localhost:54159/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` so socket.io does not load properly.  What URL are you using to load the web page in the browser?  That appears to have the correct port in it because `main.js` seems like it is running.

Comment: I'd suggest changing this: `<script src="http://localhost:54159/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` to this: `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`.  Then, it will automatically take the port from the web page.

Comment: The Brackets connection port in the screenshot is probably the debugger for your server, not the web server for your server.

Comment: I just changed the port in chat.html to this: <script src="http://localhost:58228/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> and the URL I am using is this: http://localhost:58228/public/chat.html in Google Chrome

Comment: The output from this: `console.log(\`Server running on port ${PORT}\`)` when you start your server should show you what port your server is running on.

Comment: Let me change that

Comment: I changed <script src="http://localhost:54159/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> to this: <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> and also I checked the output from this  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`) and the outport information is Server running on port 58228

Comment: And ... what happened after you made that change?

Comment: But even with those changes it still says io is undefined. I am using Brackets as the debugger not as the web server for the server

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:58228/public/chat.html

Comment: This URL which is what I am using as the web server for the server still says io is undefined

Comment: It says Cannot GET /public/chat.html

Comment: OK, that's getting somewhere.  That means your `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` is not correct.  Change the URL to `/chat.html`.  For `/public/chat.html` to work, `chat.html` would have to be located in `public/public/chat.html` on your server's hard drive, but I assume it's not and it's in `public/chat.html`.  Your `express.static()` line is pointing at `public` so that's the top of the tree it looks in.  Any other paths in the URL are relative to that.

Comment: Oh, and restart your server after any of these changes.

Comment: How do I restart the server?

Comment: That depends upon how you started it.  This is all very basic stuff.  You would probably benefit from finding a simple tutorial and following that since we don't usually cover "from scratch" tutorials here as that's much longer content than fits well in an answer here.

Comment: Okay. I will look that up. Thank you. I also edited the question to show you the folder structure to see if the path is correct

Comment: So it should be chatroom/public/chat.html and chatroom/public/index.html and chatroom/server.js and chatroom/public/js/main.js

Comment: So do you mean change this: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); to app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/chat.html')));

Comment: I did app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/chat.html'))); and it worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: No.  Wherever you're referencing `/public/chat.html`, change that.  Leave the `express.static()` line as it was.  Please find a good tutorial and follow that.  You have lots to learn and that would help.

Comment: Yes I left express.static() line as it was and I only changed /public/chat.html

Comment: That did fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

OK, I guess I'll summarize the recommended changes our exchange in the comments:

Change this:

```
<script src="http://localhost:54159/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

That removes the need for you to specify the port (which was incorrect anyway).

---

Change:

```
/public/chat.html
```

to:

```
/chat.html
```

so that it matches up with where your `express.static()` line is looking.   For `/public/chat.html` to work, `chat.html` would have to be located in `public/public/chat.html` on your server's hard drive, but I assume it's not and it's likely in `public/chat.html`. Your `express.static()` line is pointing at `public` so that's the top of the tree it looks in. Any other paths in the URL are relative to that.

---

And, anytime you make a change in client or server code, make sure and restart your server to make sure all recent changes are being used.

---

If you're unsure at all about what port your server is running on, then look at the results of this when your server starts up:

```
console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)
```

That will tell you port its running on.  The brackets log reference to a port is probably brackets connected to the nodejs debugger which will be on a different port from your web server.